# Accessing data through API Versioning in Rails Console (uninitialised constant)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Usually, when I want to access data of a particular user in the rails console, I can call something like 'User.first.posts' and this will return an array of the first user's posts/attributes.

However, how do I play with the console like this when the controller/routes are in an API namespace (eg. api/v1/x). As when I call 'User.first.groups' (the groups are in this API namespace), I get an uninitialized constant error.

Do I need to reference the namespace in the console?

Comment: What is the content of  your user model and group model files?Specifically looking for how you’re declaring the has_many in the User model and how you’re naming the Griup model in the API namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace of the controller / routes are independent and do not affect the namespace of your model. However, if your models also have a namespace you need to use it in the console too. You can prepend the namespace with the `::` syntax like `Api::User`.